# Three patterns on DVD grating

Tags: optics, diffraction

Recently, I attempted to use my DVD as a reflective diffraction grating. The setup is shown below: a green laser is shone on the DVD, and the diffraction pattern is shown on the wall.

[image: setup of the experiment]

However, in one picture I noticed there were in fact three patterns being shown:

[image: three patterns]

The three patterns were the small horizontal interference pattern, a larger spaced vertical  pattern, as well as a sharp vertical line at an angle from the center vertical pattern. What exactly is the reason why there are three distinct patterns, like the ones shown, when shining a laser on a DVD?

Comment: In each of the examples, where on the DVD were you shining the light from the laser?

Comment: Roughly the same place on the DVD, as shown in the first picture

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the precise geometry of the light and DVD; my best conjecture is some form of aberration. It is also hard to rule out the possibility of a secondary reflection from something else along the way!